# How to selectively put values into a dataframe columns after flattening the dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to use pandas data frame and I'm actually stuck with a problem. I have one dataframe, which looks like this:

```
Name   SubName     ATTR      VAL
GSKT     SW        type      circular
GSKT     SW        size      2mm
GSKT     SW        shape     square
GSKT     SW        tip       bend
GST      WW        shape     square
GST      WW        tip       tilt
GST      WW        size      3mm
```

I have a string that will lookup through this data frame and picks up the words. The string that I'd use to lookup through the data frame is something like this:

**GSKT SW square 2mm circular bend** 1st String

**GST  WW square 3mm tilt** 2nd String

Upon given this 1st string and looking up through the dataframe mentioned above I'd like to get an output like this:

```
Name  SubName    type       size   shape   tip
GSKT    SW       circular   3mm    square  tilt
```

Upon given this 2nd string and looking up through the dataframe mentioned above I'd like to get an output like this:

```
Name  SubName    type       size   shape   tip
GST    WW        Nan        2mm    square  bend
```

I will do this for a huge set of data, but right now I'm trying it out on this small subset.

This is my current code:

```
main_dict = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx')
header = main_dict.iloc[:,0:2]
data = main_dict.iloc[:,2:4]
matr_desc = "AA BB  2mm circular bend".split()

for i,j in enumerate(main_dict['Attribute']):
  for k,l in enumerate(main_dict['Values']):
    print(l)
    header[j][k] = l

main_dict.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Subname'], columns='ATTR', 
                                  values='VAL', aggfunc='first')
```

After this I am getting stuck, I know this might be very easy but since I am new I'm having a bit of difficulty constructing this.

The output I am getting for this is attached in the image section (Output_heading). The output structure I need is also attached in the below section.

Basically based on the input string I need to find an ATTR - VAL pair based on the Dataframe mentioned above.

The example output type is also posted above, mentioning it again for convenience:
1st String:

```
Name  SubName    type       size   shape   tip
GSKT    SW       circular   2mm    square  bend
```

2nd String:

```
Name  SubName    type       size   shape   tip
GST    WW        Nan        2mm    square  bend
```

[image: Output I got from the answer below]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to change your input dataframe example somewhat to show what you really need. Maybe add some new rows with other values for `Name` and `SubName`.

Comment: I updated it, I cannot write the exact names hence I used examples with a pretty close resemblance.

Comment: That does not change anything. My point is, does your dataframe only contain rows with the same `Name` and `SubName`? There should be rows with other values, right? Say `GSKT2` and `SW2`. What happens in that case? Otherwise, I'm not sure what the problem is since the `pivot_table` part will give you the wanted output.

Comment: Yes, that is also there.

Comment: Can you add it to the example input? And the expected output (if it changes).

Comment: I updated it now. Please check it now.

Comment: If I understood correctly and if `Name` and `SubName` are unique, you could simply get those two from the input string through by using `split` on the string. Then find the relevant rows in the dataframe (after `pivot_table`) by something like: `df[(df['Name'] == split_str[0]) & (df['SubName'] == split_str[1])]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
df.ATTR=pd.Categorical(df.ATTR,['type','size','shape','tip'],ordered=True)
df.pivot_table(index=['Name','SubName'],columns=['ATTR'],values='VAL',
                aggfunc='first')
```

---

```
ATTR              type size   shape   tip
Name SubName                             
GST  SAP      circular  2mm  square  bend
```